# Front chainring spacing difference between Shimano and Campagnolo?

Tags: shimano, derailleur, crankset, campagnolo, derailleur-front

I want to upgrade my mid 80s road bike from a 50 tooth to a 53. But the BCD of the big triple chainring is some rare standard that it costs less to buy a whole (used) crank instead. And of course this saves some weight ;)
Currently the crank is a Sugino with Shimano Deore derailleurs and 105 indexed toptube shifters. I know that this will get me a 'empty spot' in my shifters. I now did get some really good deal on a Campagnolo Veloce 53/39 crank. Is this compatible with the Shimano tech? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which number of speeds the Campagnolo crank is for?

Comment: Not sure about your shifters - are they toptube as stated or downtube or stem shifters?  AND are they really indexed or are they just notched?  Can they be changed to friction shifting (which is ideal for the front mech)

Answer (score 1):

Campagnolo cranks should work just fine. They use the same spacing between tha chainrings as Shimano cranks and work fine in practise from my experience.

**[Detailed explanation of bicycle cranks cross-compatibility](https://bike.bikegremlin.com/2016/10/13/bicycle-crankset-compatibility/)**.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I see you've posted a few answers, which is much appreciated. This one's rather short, though. Could you give more information? Some evidence or explanation that you're right? At the moment this answer is at the level of "Somebody on the internet says", and it's impossible to tell if that kind of answer is true or false. Thanks!

Comment: I think the question is not compatibility between Shimano and Campagnolo but between mid-80s spacing and whatever crank the OP is considering.

Comment: It still boils down to chainring spacing, which is fine.

Comment: Chainring spacing is determined by chain width.  For a given chain width you want a given spacing, regardless of brand.

Comment: While this is true for rear chainrings (cassettes), front chainring spacing is a lot greater than the chain outer width, regardless of the number of speeds the chainrings are marketed for, so mix-matching of these has worked perfectly fine for me.